# Concatenating anchor tag within HTML

Tags: c#, html, datetime

This:

```
"<a href='http://localhost:6171/activity/index/?Id='" + x.EmpId + "&date=" + DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString() + ">Click here</a>";
```

renders in the mail as this:

```
http://localhost:6171/activity/index/?Id=
```

Where it should be like this:

```
http://localhost:6171/activity/index/?Id=57&date=16/01/2018
```

Comment: Don't close the href attribute. `"<a href='http://localhost:6171/activity/index/?Id=" + x.EmpId + "&date=" + DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString() + "'>Click here</a>";`

Comment: Try this:  `"<a href = 'http://localhost:6171/activity/index/?Id="+x.EmpId+"&date="+DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString()+"'>Click Me</a>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should append it within the `href` attribute like:

```
  "<a href='http://localhost:6171/activity/index/?Id=" + x.EmpId + "&date=" 
+ DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString() + "'>Click Me</a>";
```